# Saving a brute force result for future use?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, memoization, brute-force

I am working on a program (in C++, but the specific programming language doesn't really matter for this question) that uses a brute force method to solve an intermediate step of a certain problem rather than using a pre-determined mathematical approach.

It works fine, but the computation time is long (as expected, because brute force can take a long time.)

I am OK with the computation time being long for the first instance of a particular input, but I want to incorporate some way to store this result and look it up for all future instances of the program running, rather than needing to recalculate it each time (thus reducing computation time).

My first thought is to simply store the results in a plain text file and refer to this text file as necessary to extract the result (if the result exists in the file), but this seems non-ideal considering if the text file is somehow lost or manually changed, then we are back to where we started.

My question is: Is there any way to store this type of result inside the program itself, so that next time I run the program, it simply looks up the result for a particular input rather than needing to brute force solve the problem again that it already solved?

I realize this question may be deemed too broad but I am hoping that someone can at least tell me whether my approach is a good approach, and if not, what should be done instead or what should I research? I am not sure if there is an actual name for this type of problem or not.

Comment: [There you go](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=memoization).

Comment: I would say even though it may not be ideal (saving data in files), it generally is what is done for saving values between program instances. If you are worried the file may be modified you could hash the file, store the hash in the file, then when you reload it check the file (not including the hash) hashes to the same value. Your program should be designed to handle edge cases where files are deleted or missing.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, didn't know what the actual term was called. I'll add that tag to the question.

Comment: unless the computation can be done at compile time, then no you cannot embed it in the executable. You need to use some form of storing, e.g. file, database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to store this type of result inside the program itself, so that next time I run the program

*No*.

When the program terminates, its memory is free'd, so is all its data.

So, if you really want to store these computed results, you would need to use text or binary files. In the unlikely event of a file been modified or deleted, make your program catch that case, and recompute. This is something logical, since you don't expect files to be deleted/corrupted regularly, I guess.

You could even use a database, but this would be an overkill IMHO.

---

However, what you described fetched Dynamic Programming and Memoization into mind, you might want to look at these terms and see if you can benefit.

Comment: Great answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!